# Would you use the word "flight" to describe the movement of a spacecraft going from Earth to Mars?

Tags: word-usage

Would you use the word "flight" to describe the movement of a spacecraft going from Earth to Mars? I am seriously wondering if the word flight can be used in such a way in the context of a science fiction movie. I would like to believe you can, but I am not sure.

Comment: I have to downvote this question, because it seems like no prior research was done. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flight), [A-H](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=flight), [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/flight), and [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/flight) all specifically mention "space" in their first or second definition. Here on the Stack Exchange, we expect users (especially those who have asked over 200 questions already) to at least do a modicum of research before asking their question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly: the word is well established in that sense. See for example [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_spaceflight) (the article mostly uses the single word "spaceflight", but sometimes just "flight").